# Does Win32 allow applications that both use Console and Windowing?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

C# spoils me in that I can write an application that targets the 'Console', while still using windowing. This is super useful for debugging, but alas, I am at a loss: can applications in Win32 that target `/SUB-SYSTEM:WINDOWS` also use the console?

Comment: It might be easier to make a console program that also uses WIN32 functions for GUI handling.

Comment: Sure, use AllocConsole().  Or change the sub-system to console, like you did in your C# program.  Which does require that you change your entrypoint to main().  Or use the Visual Studio Output window for debug output.  Call OutputDebugString() to send text to that window.

Comment: Obviously, the answer is yes: (a) As you said, C# (.NET, actually) proves that this is possible; and (b) the console runs in a window, too, so it must be possible to have both at the same time or you wouldn't *see* the console.

Comment: @stakx: The console window is rather special, however.  It isn't even owned by your process, all of its GUI behavior is handled by `conhost.exe`.

Comment: `all of its GUI behavior is handled by conhost.exe`. (Checks Task Manager) Oh crap, this is true. Interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If you create a console application you can still create windows. Just like a non-console application you still have to have [get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [dispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) window messages. If you create a window based application you can create a console by calling [`AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Oh rad, I didn't know you could do that. How do I capture the HINSTANCE then?

Comment: Use `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`. The return value is the same as the HINSTANCE of the application.